# How to add color banding with shader

Tags: shader, metal

This sounds odd. But I'm trying to replicate an old dos 16 bit game. The game had some really rough gradients that had some nice color banding. I want to replicate those bands.

When I implemented the shader it obviously renders the gradient very smoothly. Which looks nice but not authentic. I'm wondering how I can fake those bands within the fragment shader. What kind of algorithm leaves bands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to "bin" the color values. Normally RGB would have values between 0 and 255 (or 0-1 if you're using floats, but in 256 steps). Try to reduce this to 16 steps. So everything between 0 and 16 becomes 0, everything between 16 and 32 becomes 16, etc. In code it would be something like: `floor(color / 16)*16`.

Comment: This solution will give you more artistic control than manipulating the bit depth of the color target itself. Once you've quantized the colors in this way, you could also index into a pre-selected color palette that mimics the original system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a 4444 render target, there should be visible banding on that.

If that doesn't give sufficient control, then you could use the RGB values as a lookup into a 3D texture with point filtering. The entries in the 3D texture could be used to define an arbitrary limited colour palette.